# How to determine version of OpenView Server installed on Management Server?

Tags: unix

How to determine version of OpenView Server installed on HPUX based Management Server? Is Network Node Manager part of OpenView Operations server and its something need to be installed separately. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OpenView Admin Reference guide:

To get detailed information about the installed version of OVO on
UNIX systems, use the what(1) command.

For example, for HP-UX 11.x managed nodes, enter the following:
what /opt/OV/bin/OpC/opc*

Answer (score 1):

The command to check the installed Operations Manager version

opcsv -v